# Label images in python for classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have ~1400 images in two folder where folder name is the label for image. I am iterating over each folder and appending it in an array along with label. Later i am passing it to my neural network model.

```
for folder in files:
   sdir = dir + "\\"
   sdir = sdir + folder
   print("inside loop " +sdir)
   count = 0
   for image in os.listdir(sdir):
     img = cv2.imread(image)
     count = count + 1
     if count <= 450:
       x_train.append(img)
       y_train.append(folder)
     else:
       x_test.append(img)
       y_test.append(folder)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.softmax))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 43, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=5)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 776, in fit
    shuffle=shuffle)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2266, in _standardize_user_data
    'array or a list of arrays. You passed: x=' + str(x))
ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays.
```

Comment: can you show us the part of the code where you do the fitting? i.e `model.fit`. The error comes from there but without knowing exactly what you are doing it's difficult to help more.

Comment: Your error is coming from `File "testing.py", line 43, in <module>` on the line `model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=5)` which is not in the code you posted.

Comment: model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

Line 43 is model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=5) @ZaccharieRamzi

Comment: Edit your question with it so that it's easier for everyone to see.

Comment: Please do *not* use the comments space to post code which should already be part of your question - edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that your issue is due to the fact that `files` is probably a list of strings and therefore that `folder`(which you are passing as a label to your network) is a string, whereas the network will want integer labels.

Therefore, depending on how many labels you have (two, if I understand correctly), you could define a dictionary

```
labels_to_ints = dict(zip(files,[0,1]))
```

to map your strings to integer labels, and then instead of `y_train.append(folder)`, use

```
y_train.append(labels_to_ints[folder])
```

(and correspondingly for `y_test`).

Of course, there are other ways to perform this mapping.