# label our grayscale images using corresponding directories

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to label my grayscale images for my CNN model. At this stage I aim for binary classification (Normal VS Fault conditions). I have distributed my images to two separate folders (Normal and Fault) and want to use the corresponding directories in my codes. However, I did not find a resource for labelling grayscale images using directories. Does any one know how we can label our grayscale images using directories. I can ask my question in this way as well, can we label our grayscale images using ImageDataGenerator function?

NOTE: I use following codes, but it converts my grayscale images to coloured ones.

train_path = 'the directory'

train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) 
.flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(64,64), classes=['Normal','fault'], batch_size=10)

Best regards.

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56198117/label-images-in-python-for-classification

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a training dataframe having 2 columns `image_path` and `label` and then iterate through the different directories and save the directory name in `label` column and path of the image in `image_path` column like below

```
import pandas as pd
   
data = pd.DataFrame()
  
images = [ ]
label = [ ]
for i in os.listdir( normal_directory_path ):
      images.append( normal_directory_path/i)
      label.append( "Normal" )

# similarly for fault directory
```

Then shuffle the dataset and then you can use `dataloader`  to load the dataset into batches and while loading open the image_path and extract the image array out of it and train the model.

Answer (score 0):

VGG is an artificial neural network trained for images having three channels. If you take a glance at the official document (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/preprocess_input), you will see that this preprocessing method accepts images having three channels, and preprocesses them (again from the document):

> Returns
> Preprocessed numpy.array or a tf.Tensor with type float32.
> The images are converted from RGB to BGR, then each color channel is zero-centered with respect to the ImageNet dataset, without scaling.

So, if you are going to feed grayscale images to your model, you need to do the preprocessing yourself. To do so, you will need ImageNet dataset statistics like "mean" value, to zero center every pixel in your images. This mean will be also per channel, so just take the weighted mean of the three channels (w.r.t. Colorimetric (perceptual luminance-preserving) conversion to grayscale) to find one channel mean.

References: Colorimetric (perceptual luminance-preserving) conversion to grayscale -https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know what does vgg16 image Pre-processing does to the images? is it like the images are converted from RGB to BGR, then each color channel is zero-centered, without scaling?

Comment: You're welcome. It is what the document says. However, vgg zero-centers the images with respect to the r, g, b means of ImageNet dataset. Because your image is grayscale, you will have to convert the r, g, b means to grayscale means, with the help of the formula on this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale  (So, mean_gray = mean_rgb.r * 0.2126 + mean_rgb.g*0.7152 + mean_rgb.b*0.0722, credits to Wikipedia). This is what I would do. I'm not sure if it works or not, but hopefully works.

Comment: Thank you very much, Abdullatif for your great comments. I found the paper for VGG16, in which they say for VGG16 we normalized R, G and B values with respect to the whole data set (e.g. new R= (R - Mean of all the Rs in the data set). Now I applied the VGG16 to my grayscale images (with three channels R=G=B), but the resulted images are surprisingly colored (R not equal G not equal B)! the formula you mentioned, is it for converting grayscale to colored images, and when you say mean_rgb.r do you mean of R,G and B in each pixel multiplied by R value of that pixel?

Comment: Hi Mostafa, mean_gray is the mean value of pixels, as if all the dataset was grayscale. Because you work with grayscaled images, and the dataset statistics are calculated according to rgb, you will have to convert these statistics to grayscale so that you can use them with your algorithm. Either you need to have grayscale images to process, or you need to normalize or zero center them according to the grayscale statistics.